# Internal Server Error and Https

Tags: php, ssl, cloudflare

I have a shared host and for Https, I use CloudFlare flexible SSL to access my website via https.
The problem is i can't POST a request to my PHP scripts with https.
I test it with posthere.io, when I send a POST request to http version of script, it is ok, but when I send it to https version it causes "Internal Server Error".

Is it related to Host Provider? I checked host logs and there is no log for these requests.

Comment: Please add your script